# How to stub an axios instance that is passed as a constructor parameter and used inside a method?

Tags: javascript, axios, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to pass a stubbed instance of axios into the constructor of an object so that when I use a method of that object in a test I can control the response of the request and test the rest of the code of the method independent of the request.

My code looks like this:

```js
const requestUrl = new URL( this.iamTokenUrl );  
const requestOptions = {
    url: requestUrl.href,
    auth: {
        username: this.id,
        password: this.password,
    },
    proxy: false,
    json: true,
    timeout: 10000,
};  
const response = await this.req( requestOptions );
const token = response.data.access_token;

return token;
```

and with req being an axios instance passed in when the original object is constructed. In my test I construct the object with a stubbed instance passed in but when the object method is called it calls the actual axios request and not the stubbed version:

```js
const tokenObj = require( '../token' );

const axiosStub = axios.create();

describe( 'token request', function test() {
    let tokenObj;

    beforeEach( () => {
        sinon.stub( axiosStub, 'request' ).resolves( Promise.resolve( { access_token: 'test_access_token' } ) );
const testProperties = { TESTUSER: 'test_user_id', TEST_PASS: 'test_user_password', TEST_URL: 'fake_url' };
        techToken = new TechToken(
            testProperties.TEST_USER,
            testProperties.TEST_PASS,
            testProperties.TEST_URL,
            {
                req: axiosStub,
            }
        );
    } );

    it( 'should request new tech token', async ( done ) => {
        const returnedTechToken = await techToken.requestTechToken();

        expect( returnedTechToken ).to.equal( 'test_access_token' );
        done();
    } );

    afterEach( () => {
        sinon.reset();
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Please provide minimal, complete code. Your code is incomplete